# Creation of Parallel Sqoop jobs failed

Tags: sqoop

I am creating parallel sqoop jobs using my script but after executing command to list all the created sqoop jobs, i only get one sqoop job.

Comment: Can you post some examples on how you are trying to run the parallel sqoop jobs from script ?? Also did you tried using them in sequential way to validate the syntax part ?